# IPTABLES not blocking EoIP Tunnel

Tags: iptables, vpn, mikrotik, tunnel, routeros

So I decided to play with `EoIP Tunnels` today on two VMs which I installed free trial `RouterOS` on them.

I set rules on `iptables` on the hypervisor (which is `Proxmox`) that prevents any input to vms except my pc, but my `OUTPUT` policy is `ACCEPT`.

Now I can't `ping` vms from anywhere except my pc and I can't `ping` my two vms (`RouterOS`) from each other, but `EoIP Tunnel` works fine and I'm routing packets from one `RouterOS` to another one.

`iptables` config on both vms:

```
IN ACCEPT -source a.b.c.d
IN DROP
```

(a.b.c.d is IP of my pc)

What I am doing wrong?

RouterOSs' config:

VM1:

```
/ip address
#   ADDRESS            NETWORK         INTERFACE                              
0   r.o.s.1/32         m.a.i.n         ether1                                 
1   172.22.22.1/30     172.22.22.0     eoiptunnel

/ip route
#      DST-ADDRESS        PREF-SRC        GATEWAY            DISTANCE
0 A S  0.0.0.0/0                          172.22.22.2               1
1 ADC  m.a.i.n/32         r.o.s.1         ether1                    0
2 ADC  172.22.22.0/30     172.22.22.1     eoiptunnel                0
```

VM2:

```
/ip address
#   ADDRESS            NETWORK         INTERFACE                              
0   r.o.s.2/32         m.a.i.n         ether1                                 
1   172.22.22.2/30     172.22.22.0     eoiptunnel
```

IPs:

```
r.o.s.1 : Router OS 1
r.o.s.2 : Router OS 2
m.a.i.n : Main Server IP
```

---

I monitor traffic on my host server by `iptraf` and I watched two `RouterOS`s are seeing each other via another interface, actually I realize that for every VM, `proxmox` creates 4 interfaces, therefore I assume "some" packets between two VMs which are on the same bridge go through another interface.

I must read the documentation on multiple interfaces created by `proxmox` upon creating each VM.

Comment: How are you verifying your EOIP connectivity between your RouterOSs, if they cannot ping each other?

Comment: And it would be helpful to send Proxmox iptables rules.
Iptables -L

Comment: @Arash I'm routing for example (4.2.2.4) to go through second RouterOS on VPN, when I block outgoing packets to 4.2.2.4, I can't ping 4.2.2.4, therefore I can verify my vpn is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguably you're doing nothing wrong.

Your `iptables` rules are blocking traffic into your Proxmox environment, and your two guests are talking to each other across the internal bridge.

The `iptables` rules won't touch bridge traffic between VMs, and that's by design. (If you routed traffic from one VM to the other via your host, or you tried to ping between a VM and the host, `iptables` rules would apply.)

Comment: I suppose I should put firewall on RouterOS itself to block packets coming from internal bridge.